# Which color sheme does Yolo expect?

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'am testing some neural networks and I could not find official information about the color sheme for the Yolo networks.

I only found the following github link (https://github.com/longcw/yolo2-pytorch) and this says RGB is needed. Is this correct?

Comment: What else did you expect? Do you have any reason to assume that despite the documentation, the actual "color scheme" should be HSL ?

Comment: I was just wondering why there is no public Statement. Thanks